# auto-py-to-exe File not found error on run

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pygui

i know i should share the code instead of image but please refer image for my path.
[This is my path of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bjKZ.png)

setup file contains

```
from Functions.MainWindow import Ui
def OpenMainwindow(self):
    try:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = Ui()
        window.show()
        app.exec_()
        # Ui()
    except Exception as es:
        print(es)
```

And the Inside form file i loaded UI file  from other folder

```
uic.loadUi(r"./BAJARANGBALI/Forms/MainWindow.ui", self)
```

but when i make exe using auto-py-to-exe during running of exe file it shows file not found.[Errno 2] No such file or directory: './Forms/MainWindow.ui'.

I tried every path ,Even tried by moving exe to that path but no result.

I am new to stackoverflow i hope i tried my best to describe my issue.Thanks

Comment: your file path is JAY BAJRANG/BAJRANGBALI in B DRIVE but here you gave path ./BAJRANGBALI you should give full path then it will work. ./ use for same working directory where you project is. but if you have file outside then give full path like "B:\Jay Bajrangbali then folder name and then file location. If you dont know how to give path then just click on top Address bar and select copy and paste in python

Comment: No the exe i am going to make should be portable.Thats the problem.